# Does Skype For Business (Lync 2015) support inbound History-Info headers

Tags: lync, sip-server, skype-for-business

Sniffing with Wireshark I can see that an inbound INVITE from our PSTN sip trunk contains a history-info header, but this header is not forwarded to our endpoint application server where I want to pick it up.

The sip logs on the mediation server does not show the history-info header, so it seems that the Lync 2015 mediation server is tampering with the INVITE requests from the PSTN trunk even before it is logging inbound sip messages.

I have read that Lync 2013 does not support inbound history-info headers, [Reference: History-info Inbound is not supported](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38820), but am hoping that this does not hold true for 2015.

Is it possible to configure Lync 2015 to forward the history-info header from inbound invites or are they not supported at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the history-info header is only supported in one direction, outbound to PSTN. This is documented here [Lync Server 2013: Headers for SIP Trunking](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/38820).

**On page 6 we read** • History-info Inbound is not supported. The Mediation Server will not forward any received History-Info headers

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i have come across the same problem previously and i found that it is still not supported, i cannot provide a link though as this was some time ago.